# Get BLE pairing dialog on unsuccesful pairing on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an app with specific BLE device, but problem is that this device needs pairing to work properly. So first pairing popup is automatic, but user can fail to enter proper PIN or dismiss it by accident and I have no means to show it again now. I know when pairing was unsuccessful by testing to write to one characteristic and it fails, problem is not only to show pairing dialog again to user without reseting whole app and/or device.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again after fidlign about for several hours I managed to find solution. 
First device needs to be disconnected with call to:
cancelPeripheralConnection(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral)
Wait for disconnect response from delegate and then call connect with:
func connect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, options: [String : Any]? = nil)
This will fire pairing dialog again.

Another problems with pairing are:
- unpairing device inside app from phone - it doesn't work unless you go to phone settings and "forget" device there or kill app and start again. 
- there is no callback or events for pairing dialog. As developer you can never know if pairing was success or not. All I could do was just set a timer and check after 15seconds if pairing was success (write something to test characteristic), but that puts a lot more troubles in code. Shame as it seems Apple did just forget about pairing on iOS, while for macOS there is pairing delegate in IOBluetooth.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I'm experiencing this same issue.